# Nodejs module export returns undefined

Tags: node.js

I am using the [recursive-readdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir) module to list all files types in a directory, the code below works, however I get "undefined" being displayed before my array.

The code below is inserted into a js file "test.js" and is ran from the cmd line using "node test.js".

Any suggestings on how best to return an array of all the required files without the undefined string being returned?

```
    const recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
    exports.file = function() {
      recursive(__dirname, ['!*.md'], function(error, files) {
       var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          arr.push(files[i]);
        }
        console.log(arr);
      });
    };
    console.log( exports.file() );
```

Comment: That's because exports.file doesn't return anything. So instead of `console.log( exports.file() );` do just `exports.file()`

Comment: thanks @molda your suggestion was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `exports.file` does not have a return value, which is why you get `undefined` when you try to log it.

If you want the caller of `exports.file` to have access to the files, you need to update `exports.file` to take a callback that can be invoked with the files as a parameter.

```
const recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
exports.file = function(callback) {
  recursive(__dirname, ['!*.md'], function(error, files) {
   var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      arr.push(files[i]);
    }
    console.log(arr);
    callback(error, arr);
  });
};

exports.file(function(error, files) {
  console.log(files);
});
```

That will log the files with minimal changes to your original code.

Depending on how you need this code to evolve, you can probably simplify this quite a bit. First, do you really need `arr` in addition to `files`? If not, you can simply pass `files` to the callback:

```
const recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
exports.file = function(callback) {
  recursive(__dirname, ['!*.md'], function(error, files) {
    callback(error, files);
  });
};

exports.file(function(error, files) {
  console.log(files);
});
```

And now since your callback to `recursive` just invokes the callback to `exports.file`, you could simply pass the `exports.file` callback to `recursive`

```
const recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
exports.file = function(callback) {
  recursive(__dirname, ['!*.md'], callback);
};

exports.file(function(error, files) {
  console.log(files);
});
```